# combine two bash commands into a one shortcut prompt

Tags: git, bash

I'm not great with bash, but i'd like to write a shortcut, such as 'opendev', that opens a url in a browser and opens the current git topic branch i'm on. (only needs to work on os x). Inspiration here is from heroku CTL's "heroku open".

I've got the basics here but i'm not sure how to connect them.

```
#This launches my default browser and opens a url
open http://branchname.dev.foobar.com
#this returns the current git topic branch name  i'm working on
git branch | grep "*" | sed "s/* //"
```

Any help would be amazing, since i'm failing.

Comment: A better way to get the current branch name is `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`, so your command will become: `br=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD); open http://$br.dev.foobar.com`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

put the following in your `.bashrc` or similar:

```
opendev() {
    open http://$(git branch | grep "*" | sed "s/* //").dev.foobar.com
}
```

Comment: Instead of two processes I would suggest one awk process. Something like this: `awk '/\*/{sub("\* ",""); print}'`

Answer (score 1):

```
branch=$(git branch | grep "*" | sed "s/* //")
open "http://$branch.dev.foobar.com"
```